# How to redirect one domain to another (wildcard) without inheriting the back links?

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, backlinks

I want to redirect my old domain to a new one. Im running a blog and I need to use wildcard redirect so all the posts will be redirected accordingly. But I don't want to inherit the backlinks in those posts. I want a fresh site! How to do this?

Comment: So, the only reason to redirect is to speed up the indexing of your new site?

Comment: @w3d No... I have a site. I want to redirect it to a new domain. Changing the domain name.

Comment: But... "without inheriting the back links"?

Comment: "the backlinks **in** those posts." - The backlinks **to** those posts? Can you just clarify what _you_ mean by a "backlink"? Backlinks are links to your pages from other sites - yes?

Answer (score 1):

Webmasters that have been hit by Google's algorithms or Google's evil penguin update attempting to get out of the penalty by registering a new domain and then redirecting the old to new will be left disappointed. Sadly its not a case of simply redirecting all visitors from old to new because that would defeat the objective of the punishment they have enforced.

All SEO Friendly Redirects Pass Juice

There is not form of redirecting without passing link juice across since a 301 and even a 302 will pass the links across and eventually the penalty that will occur when the Algorithms catch up (This has been tried and tested thousands of times by blackhatters).

Cloaking is Bad Okay!

You could look at the option of redirecting using a cloaking method either a PHP method or a JavaScript that Google is unable to read however this also breaks Google's ruling under cloaking.

Ideal SEO Friendly Options

- Wait for the penalty to be lifted... takes donkeys.
- Redirect all URLS on the old domain to the root i.e `http://www.example.com/we-have-moved/` With a nofollow link something like `<a href="http://www.newdomain.com/" title="We've Moved" rel="nofollow">Click to go to the new site</a>`

Comment: What is "takes donkeys"?  Is that a British slang?

Comment: Ya, means takes ages ;)

Comment: Then I guess I won't down vote you for stealing farm animals. :-)